# Knockout foreach array checkboxes are not visually updating

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a json array that has elements created in a foreach databind.
Then I'm retaining the selected object in that array so that I can have independent "Save Changes" buttons for each object in that array.  All of that is working (primarycontactname for example) except the binding for the checkboxes.

```
<div class="container span8" data-bind="foreach: locationssubscribed">
  <div class="well span3" data-bind="click: $parent.selectedLocationSubscribed">
    <input type="text" class="span3" data-bind="value: primarycontactname" placeholder="Contact Name.." />
    <br />      
    <div class="checkbox" data-bind="visible: (vendorbringinggifts() === 0 || vendorbringinggifts() === vendorid())">
      <input id="chkGiftsAreBeingBrought" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: giftsarebeingbrought" />
    </div>
    <button data-bind="click: $root.saveVendorToLocation, enable: needsave, text: needsave() ? 'Save Location Changes' : 'No Changes to Save', css: { 'btn-primary': needsave }" class="btn">Save Location Changes</button>
  </div>
</div
```

The checkboxes load correctly based on the giftsarebeingbrought observable in each array object but when clicking the checkbox the visible check doesn't toggle.  Using the debugger I can see that the observable giftsarebeingbrought in the original array and in the selectedLocationSubscribed are toggling on the first click but then do not toggle again on subsequent clicks and the visual checkbox never changes after the initial binding.

```
{
    "locationssubscribed": [
    {
      "vendortolocationid": 10,
      "primarycontactname": "Fake Name1",
      "vendorbringinggifts": 0,
      "giftsarebeingbrought": false,
      "needsave": false
    },
    {
      "vendortolocationid": 11,
      "primarycontactname": "Fake Name2",
      "vendorbringinggifts": 0,
      "giftsarebeingbrought": false,
      "needsave": false
    },
    {
      "vendortolocationid": 12,
      "primarycontactname": "Fake Name3",
      "vendorbringinggifts": 0,
      "giftsarebeingbrought": false,
      "needsave": false
    },
    {
      "vendortolocationid": 13,
      "primarycontactname": "Fake Name4",
      "vendorbringinggifts": 0,
      "giftsarebeingbrought": false,
      "needsave": false
    }
  ],
  "selectedLocationSubscribed": {
    "vendortolocationid": 12,
    "primarycontactname": "Fake Name1",
    "vendorbringinggifts": 0,
    "giftsarebeingbrought": true,
    "needsave": true
  }
}



function VendorToLocation(vtl) {
  this.vendortolocationid = ko.observable(vtl.VendorToLocationID);
  this.primarycontactname = ko.observable(vtl.PrimaryContactName);
  this.vendorbringinggifts = ko.observable(vtl.VendorBringingGifts);
  this.giftsarebeingbrought = ko.observable(vtl.GiftsAreBeingBrought);
  this.needsave = ko.observable(false);
}

function VendorViewModel() {
  var self = this;
      self.locationssubscribed = ko.observableArray();
  self.selectedLocationSubscribed = ko.observable();
  self.selectedLocationSubscribed.subscribe(function (ftl) {
    if (ftl !== null) {
      ftl.needsave(true);
    }
  });

  self.getLocationsAvailable = function (vendorID) {
    self.locationsavailable.removeAll();
    $.ajax($("#GetLocationsAvailableUrl").val(), {
      data: '{ "vendorID":' + vendorID + '}',
      async: false,
      success: function (allData) {
        self.locationsavailable($.map(allData, function (item) { return new LocationsAvailable(item) }));
      }
    });
  }

  self.getLocationSubscription = function (vendorID) {
    self.locationssubscribed.removeAll();
    $.ajax($("#GetLocationSubscriptionUrl").val(), {
      data: '{ "vendorID":' + vendorID + '}',
      success: function (allData) {
        self.locationssubscribed($.map(allData, function (item) { return new VendorToLocation(item) }));
      }
    });
  }


  self.saveVendorToLocation = function () {
    var url = $("#updateVendorToLocationUrl").val();
    var vendorid = self.selectedVendor().vendorid();
    var selectedLoc = self.selectedLocationSubscribed();
    $.ajax(url, {
      data: '{ "vtl" : ' + ko.toJSON(selectedLoc) + '}',
      success: function (result) {
        if (result === false) {
          toastr.error("ERROR!:  Either you or a competing vendor has chosen this location since you last loaded the webpage.  Please refresh the page.");
        } else {
          toastr.success("Vendor to location details saved");
          selectedLoc.vendortolocationid(result.VendorToLocationID);
          self.updateVendorView();  // added 170307 1030 to get vendor contact details to update automatically
          self.getActionLog(vendorid);
          selectedLoc.needsave(false);
        }
      }
    });

  };
}   

$(document).ready(function () {

  var myViewModel = new VendorViewModel();
  ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
  myViewModel.updateVendorView();
  myViewModel.getLocationSubscription(curVendorID);
}
```

The goal is to get the checkbox working correctly.  The rest of the textbox based bindings I removed to condense the post have worked correctly for years some I'm now stumped as to what I'm doing wrong with the textbox.

Comment: Ok, so I've figured out that if I remove "click: $parent.selectedLocationSubscribed" the symptom goes away but that observable is how I was doing some isDirty style tracking on the object so that I know if that panel / object needs to allow the user to save their changes.  

Any ideas how to reapply the checked binding to the element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me reconfirm, so you're trying to enable the associated button as well as check the checkbox if a user click on an element inside `<div class="well span3 ...>"`.

I put all the suggestions in the code directly.

```js
function VendorToLocation(vtl) {
  var self = this;
  self.vendortolocationid = ko.observable(vtl.vendortolocationid);
  self.primarycontactname = ko.observable(vtl.primarycontactname);
  self.vendorbringinggifts = ko.observable(vtl.vendorbringinggifts);
  self.giftsarebeingbrought = ko.observable(vtl.giftsarebeingbrought);
  self.needsave = ko.observable(vtl.needsave);

  // I prefer to put all the logic in here instead of being embedded to the HTML
  self.isCheckboxVisible = ko.pureComputed(function(){
    return self.vendorbringinggifts() === 0 || self.vendorbringinggifts() === self.vendortolocationid();
  });
}

function VendorViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.locationssubscribed = ko.observableArray(
    [
      new VendorToLocation ({
        "vendortolocationid": 10,
        "primarycontactname": "Fake Name1",
        "vendorbringinggifts": 0,
        "giftsarebeingbrought": false,
        "needsave": false
      }),
      new VendorToLocation ({
        "vendortolocationid": 11,
        "primarycontactname": "Fake Name2",
        "vendorbringinggifts": 0,
        "giftsarebeingbrought": false,
        "needsave": false
      }),
      new VendorToLocation ({
        "vendortolocationid": 12,
        "primarycontactname": "Fake Name3",
        "vendorbringinggifts": 0,
        "giftsarebeingbrought": false,
        "needsave": false
      }),
      new VendorToLocation ({
        "vendortolocationid": 13,
        "primarycontactname": "Fake Name4",
        "vendorbringinggifts": 0,
        "giftsarebeingbrought": false,
        "needsave": false
      })
    ]
  );
  
  // To store the selected location
  self.selectedLocationSubscribed = ko.observable();

  // To modify selected location, enable the button and modify the checkbox whenever user click on an element that uses this as its click event
  self.selectLocationSubscribed = function(data, event) {
    if(data !== null) { 
      self.selectedLocationSubscribed(data);
    
      // If you want to change needsave of other properties to false (disable all other buttons) before that you can do it here
      ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.locationssubscribed(), function(location) {
        if(data.vendortolocationid() !== location.vendortolocationid()){
          location.needsave(false);
          location.giftsarebeingbrought(false);
        }
      });
      // code ends here
    
      // And then you modify the selected needsave the selected object to true to enable the button
      data.needsave(true);
      data.giftsarebeingbrought(true);
    }

    // To perform the default browser click action
    return true;
  }
}   

$(document).ready(function () {
  var myViewModel = new VendorViewModel();
  ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container span8" data-bind="foreach: locationssubscribed">
  <div class="well span3" data-bind="click: $parent.selectLocationSubscribed">
    <input type="text" class="span3" data-bind="value: primarycontactname" placeholder="Contact Name.." />
    <br />      
    <div class="checkbox" data-bind="visible: (vendorbringinggifts() === 0 || vendorbringinggifts() === vendorid())">
      <input id="chkGiftsAreBeingBrought" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: giftsarebeingbrought" />
    </div>
    <button data-bind="click: $root.saveVendorToLocation, enable: needsave, text: needsave() ? 'Save Location Changes' : 'No Changes to Save', css: { 'btn-primary': needsave }" class="btn">Save Location Changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've implemented this but the issue still remains, the checkbox does not change visibly when clicked but debugging with a toJSON call shows the underlying observables are changing with the first click.  All subsequent clicks to do not change anything.  It's as if the checkbox is loosing it's 'checked' data-bind when selectedLocationSubscribed changes.

Any other ideas to make sure the elements retain their checkbox functionality?

Comment: Thank you for the help!  This is working now.  I really appreciate the time you spent on this.

Answer (score 0):

The `click` binding prevents the default action. To enable the default action, [return `true` from the event handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note-3-allowing-the-default-click-action). This means you can't directly pass an observable to the `click` binding.

```
click: $parent.handleClick
```

JS:

```
self.handleClick = function (item) {
    // do something with item
    return true;  // don't prevent default action
}
```